# How to convert spark SchemaRDD into RDD of my case class?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, parquet

In the spark docs it's clear how to create parquet files from `RDD` of your own case classes; (from the docs)

```scala
val people: RDD[Person] = ??? // An RDD of case class objects, from the previous example.

// The RDD is implicitly converted to a SchemaRDD by createSchemaRDD, allowing it to be stored using Parquet.
people.saveAsParquetFile("people.parquet")
```

But not clear how to convert back, really we want a method `readParquetFile` where we can do:

```scala
val people: RDD[Person] = sc.readParquestFile[Person](path)
```

where those values of the case class are defined are those which are read by the method.

Comment: Any updated solution on this since it was first asked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution I've come up with that requires the least amount of copy and pasting for new classes is as follows (I'd still like to see another solution though)

First you have to define your case class, and a (partially) reusable factory method

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions

case class MyClass(fooBar: Long, fred: Long)

// Here you want to auto gen these functions using macros or something
object Factories extends java.io.Serializable {
  def longLong[T](fac: (Long, Long) => T)(row: expressions.Row): T = 
    fac(row(0).asInstanceOf[Long], row(1).asInstanceOf[Long])
}
```

Some boiler plate which will already be available

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
```

The magic

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD

def camelToUnderscores(name: String) = 
  "[A-Z]".r.replaceAllIn(name, "_" + _.group(0).toLowerCase())

def getCaseMethods[T: TypeTag]: List[String] = typeOf[T].members.sorted.collect {
  case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
}.toList.map(_.toString)

def caseClassToSQLCols[T: TypeTag]: List[String] = 
  getCaseMethods[T].map(_.split(" ")(1)).map(camelToUnderscores)

def schemaRDDToRDD[T: TypeTag: ClassTag](schemaRDD: SchemaRDD, fac: expressions.Row => T) = {
  val tmpName = "tmpTableName" // Maybe should use a random string
  schemaRDD.registerAsTable(tmpName)
  sqlContext.sql("SELECT " + caseClassToSQLCols[T].mkString(", ") + " FROM " + tmpName)
  .map(fac)
}
```

Example use

```scala
val parquetFile = sqlContext.parquetFile(path)

val normalRDD: RDD[MyClass] = 
  schemaRDDToRDD[MyClass](parquetFile, Factories.longLong[MyClass](MyClass.apply))
```

See also:

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-SQL-Convert-SchemaRDD-back-to-RDD-td9071.html

Though I failed to find any example or documentation by following the JIRA link.

Answer (score 7):

An easy way is to provide your own converter `(Row) => CaseClass`. This is a bit more manual, but if you know what you are reading it should be quite straightforward.

Here is an example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD

case class User(data: String, name: String, id: Long)

def sparkSqlToUser(r: Row): Option[User] = {
    r match {
      case Row(time: String, name: String, id: Long) => Some(User(time,name, id))
      case _ => None
    }
}

val parquetData: SchemaRDD = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs://localhost/user/data.parquet")

val caseClassRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[User] = parquetData.flatMap(sparkSqlToUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple method to convert schema rdd to rdd using pyspark in Spark 1.2.1.

```
sc = SparkContext()  ## create SparkContext
srdd = sqlContext.sql(sql)
c = srdd.collect()  ## convert rdd to list
rdd = sc.parallelize(c)
```

there must be similar approach using scala.

Comment: This (collect) will work for a small data collection but not if you have a lot of records.

Comment: I think you might be missing the point of the question, we want type-provider like functionality.  Since python has a rather weak type system and is dynamic, I doubt in the python world people really care.  We are building applications that need to be highly stable, hence we use a language with a proper type system and need type-provider functionality.

Comment: sorry, i miss the point. I have a little puzzle about your solution.`sqlContext.sql("SELECT " + caseClassToSQLCols[T].mkString(", ") + " FROM " + tmpName)` returns a srdd object, so it has no map method. And map method just is used to apply a function to every element. I could not find that your code can convert the srdd to rdd. Could you tell me if i miss some important thing in your code. Thank you!

Comment: furthermore, my spark version is 1.2.1.

Answer (score -1):

Very crufty attempt. Very unconvinced this will have decent performance. Surely there must a macro-based alternative...

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.NullaryMethodType
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeRef
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Type
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.NoType
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.termNames
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror

schemaRdd.map(row => RowToCaseClass.rowToCaseClass(row.toSeq, typeOf[X], 0))

object RowToCaseClass {
  // http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2012/08/json-serialization-with-reflection-in.html
  def rowToCaseClass(record: Seq[_], t: Type, depth: Int): Any = {
    val fields = t.decls.sorted.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
    }
    val values = fields.zipWithIndex.map {
      case (field, i) =>
        field.typeSignature match {
          case NullaryMethodType(sig) if sig =:= typeOf[String] => record(i).asInstanceOf[String]
          case NullaryMethodType(sig) if sig =:= typeOf[Int] => record(i).asInstanceOf[Int]
          case NullaryMethodType(sig) =>
            if (sig.baseType(typeOf[Seq[_]].typeSymbol) != NoType) {
              sig match {
                case TypeRef(_, _, args) =>
                  record(i).asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[_]]].map {
                    r => rowToCaseClass(r, args(0), depth + 1)
                  }.toSeq
              }
            } else {
              sig match {
                case TypeRef(_, u, _) =>
                  rowToCaseClass(record(i).asInstanceOf[Seq[_]], sig, depth + 1)
              }
            }
        }
    }.asInstanceOf[Seq[Object]]
    val mirror = runtimeMirror(t.getClass.getClassLoader)
    val ctor = t.member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val klass = t.typeSymbol.asClass
    val method = mirror.reflectClass(klass).reflectConstructor(ctor)
    method.apply(values: _*)
  }
}
```