# How to match Dataframe column names to Scala case class attributes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

The column names in this example from spark-sql come from the `case class Person`.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val people: RDD[Person] = ... // An RDD of case class objects, from the previous example.

// The RDD is implicitly converted to a SchemaRDD by createSchemaRDD, allowing it to be stored using Parquet.
people.saveAsParquetFile("people.parquet")
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html

However in many cases the parameter names may be changed.  This would cause columns to not be found if the file has not been updated to reflect the change.

**How can I specify an appropriate mapping?**

I am thinking something like:

```
  val schema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("name", StringType, nullable = false),
    StructField("age", IntegerType, nullable = false)
  ))


  val ps: Seq[Person] = ???

  val personRDD = sc.parallelize(ps)

  // Apply the schema to the RDD.
  val personDF: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(personRDD, schema)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear what you want. 1. Write parquet with arbitrary names? 2. Change the parquet column names afterwards? 3. Read a parquet with arbitrary column names and "match"/map it to field of case class?

Comment: @MartinSenne How so?  I want to set column names manually and map case class params to these columns.

Comment: But you intent to have them matched automatically?

Comment: @MartinSenne please expand on that.  Like i said i want to match manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, all the mapping you need to do can be achieved with `DataFrame.select(...)`. (Here, I assume, that no type conversions need to be done.)
Given the forward- and backward-mapping as maps, the essential part is

```
val mapping = from.map{ (x:(String, String)) => personsDF(x._1).as(x._2) }.toArray
// personsDF your original dataframe  
val mappedDF = personsDF.select( mapping: _* )
```

where mapping is an array of `Column`s with alias.

### Example code

```
object Example {   

  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
  import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  object Mapping {
    val from = Map("name" -> "a", "age" -> "b")
    val to = Map("a" -> "name", "b" -> "age")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    // init
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName( "Example." )
      .setMaster( "local[*]")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    // create persons
    val persons = Seq(Person("bob", 35), Person("alice", 27))
    val personsRDD = sc.parallelize(persons, 4)
    val personsDF = personsRDD.toDF

    writeParquet( personsDF, "persons.parquet", sc, sqlContext)

    val otherPersonDF = readParquet( "persons.parquet", sc, sqlContext )
  }

  def writeParquet(personsDF: DataFrame, path:String, sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext) : Unit = {
    import Mapping.from

    val mapping = from.map{ (x:(String, String)) => personsDF(x._1).as(x._2) }.toArray

    val mappedDF = personsDF.select( mapping: _* )
    mappedDF.write.parquet("/output/path.parquet") // parquet with columns "a" and "b"
  }

  def readParquet(path: String, sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext) : Unit = {
    import Mapping.to
    val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(path) // this df has columns a and b

    val mapping = to.map{ (x:(String, String)) => df(x._1).as(x._2) }.toArray
    df.select( mapping: _* )
  }
}
```

### Remark

If you need to convert a dataframe back to an RDD[Person], then

```
val rdd : RDD[Row] = personsDF.rdd
val personsRDD : Rdd[Person] = rdd.map { r: Row => 
  Person( r.getAs("person"), r.getAs("age") )
}
```

### Alternatives

Have also a look at [How to convert spark SchemaRDD into RDD of my case class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181353/how-to-convert-spark-schemardd-into-rdd-of-my-case-class?rq=1)

Comment: Nice approach.  Do you think this would impact performance, or should it not a be factor since this is compiled  and optimized once in the internal pipeline?

Comment: I assume the latter. First, as there is Catalyst optimization / compilation. Second, selects (with alias) don't seem to be expensive operations. Though, would be interested to see some performance measurements ....

Comment: @BAR can we use jave here ? for the example given? In java dataset select method doesn't have capability to take a map?