# Spark DataFrame and renaming multiple columns (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any nicer way to prefix or rename all or multiple columns at the same time of a given SparkSQL `DataFrame` than calling multiple times `dataFrame.withColumnRenamed()`?

An example would be if I want to detect changes (using full outer join). Then I'm left with two `DataFrame`s with the same structure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest to use the select() method to perform this. In fact withColumnRenamed() method uses select() by itself. Here is example how to rename multiple columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val someDataframe: DataFrame = ...

val initialColumnNames = Seq("a", "b", "c")
val renamedColumns = initialColumnNames.map(name => col(name).as(s"renamed_$name"))
someDataframe.select(renamedColumns : _*)
```

Comment: It's more about Java API and Spark. As an example `select` expects either one String parameter and then varargs or array of `Column`s which is not consistent and also sometimes a bit annoying to use. I had to create a few helper methods to deal with this problem, but would be better to have those methods directly available in `DataFrame`.

Comment: There is another example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535273/how-to-match-dataframe-column-names-to-scala-case-class-attributes)

Comment: Did you try your code with Spark 2.0? I'm dealing with 7000 columns, see https://github.com/ramhiser/datamicroarray/wiki/Golub-(1999) . It takes forever (=never finished before my patience was over).

Comment: @JiriS do you have a java version of this? or is it we have to stick with the withColumnRenamed method?

Answer (score 2):

I think this method can help you.

```
public static Dataset<Row> renameDataFrame(Dataset<Row> dataset) {
    for (String column : dataset.columns()) {
        dataset = dataset.withColumnRenamed(column, SystemUtils.underscoreToCamelCase(column));
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

```
    public static String underscoreToCamelCase(String underscoreName) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if (underscoreName != null && underscoreName.length() > 0) {
            boolean flag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < underscoreName.length(); i++) {
                char ch = underscoreName.charAt(i);
                if ("_".charAt(0) == ch) {
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    if (flag) {
                        result.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
                        flag = false;
                    } else {
                        result.append(ch);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Where do you import `SystemUtils` from?

Comment: Custom, I added

Answer (score 0):

I heve just found the answer

```
df1_r = df1.select(*(col(x).alias(x + '_df1') for x in df1.columns))
```

at [stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778664/spark-dataframe-distinguish-columns-with-duplicated-name) (see the end of the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
or (a <- 0 to newsales.columns.length - 1) 
{ 
 var new_c = newsales.columns(a).replace('(','_').replace(')',' ').trim  
 newsales_var = newsales.withColumnRenamed(newsales.columns(a),new_c) 
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.