# Spark DataFrame and HiveSQL - Dropping a column not working?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

I have the following code:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(ctx.sc());

DataFrame df1 = sqlContext.read().json("../smthng/*.json");
DataFrame df2 = sqlContext.read().json("../else/*.json");

df1.registerTempTable("df1");
df2.registerTempTable("df2");

DataFrame df= sqlContext.sql("SELECT * " +
                             "FROM df1 " +
                             "LEFT OUTER JOIN df2 ON df1.id = df2.id " +
                             "WHERE df1.id IS NULL").drop("df1.id");
```

Here, I'm trying to make an outer join, and then drop one of the `id` columns. Apparently a join keeps both columns, and when I'm trying to work with it further on, it can't decide which one to use (I get errors like `Reference 'id' is ambiguous, could be: id#59, id#376.;`). That's why I'm trying to drop one of these columns, but even though I do use `....drop("df1.id");`, it doesn't work. Any ideas how I can drop one of the `id` columns?
Thank you!

Comment: Which spark version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.6.2.

Answer (score 2):

There is no column "df1.id" in DF created by join query hence drop is not working. Consider your query returns following DF.

```
+---+----+-----+----+
| id|name|email|  id|
+---+----+-----+----+
|  2| xxx| null|null|
|  3| zzz| null|null|
+---+----+-----+----+
```

If you call df.printSchema() you will get

```
root
|-- id: integer (nullable = false)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- email: string (nullable = true)
|-- id: integer (nullable = true)
```

So if you call drop("id"). it will drop the "id" column and will return

```
+----+-----+
|name|email|
+----+-----+
| xxx| null|
| zzz| null|
+----+-----+
```

If you want to have one "id" column in final DF then change your query to like below

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT df1.id, df1.name, df2.email " +
            "FROM df1 " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN df2 ON df1.id = df2.id " 
            +"WHERE df1.id IS NULL");
```

and it will return

```
+---+----+-----+
| id|name|email|
+---+----+-----+
|  2| xxx| null|
|  3| zzz| null|
+---+----+-----+
```

Spark DF API provides API like "alias" or "withColumnRename" to handle the duplicate columns in DF. Please also refer SO post [Spark Dataframe distinguish columns with duplicated name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778664/spark-dataframe-distinguish-columns-with-duplicated-name).

Answer (score 0):

Use columns name in the sql and also use alias -

```
DataFrame df= sqlContext.sql("SELECT Column1 as col1,Column2 as col2...ColumnN as colN" +
                             "FROM df1 " +
                             "LEFT OUTER JOIN df2 ON df1.id = df2.id " +
                             "WHERE df1.id IS NULL").drop("df1.id");
```

Hope this approach will not give u error message like "ambiguous"

Comment: But I have 30 columns in my dataset, is naming them all really the only option I have?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this by using the join like this:

```
DataFrame df = df1.join(df2, df1.col("id").equalTo(df2.col("customer_id")), "left")
            .select("*").where(df1.col("id").isNotNull())
            .drop(df1.col("id"));
```