# Spark Scala dataframe join dynamically using list of columns and joinExprs

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, join

I am creating a function which takes join keys and condition as parameters and dynamically joins two dataframes.

I understand Spark Scala Dataframe join done [the following ways](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/):

```
1) join(right: Dataset[_]): DataFrame
2) join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumn: String): DataFrame
3) join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String]): DataFrame
4) join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String], joinType: String): DataFrame
5) join(right: Dataset[_], joinExprs: Column): DataFrame
6) join(right: Dataset[_], joinExprs: Column, joinType: String): DataFrame
```

Join keys/usingColumns parameters will be a list of column names.
condition/joinExprs - not sure how to pass it, but it can be a string like `"df2(colname) == 'xyz'"`

[Based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297862/dynamically-join-two-spark-scala-dataframes-on-multiple-columns-without-hardcodi), I came up with the below. It takes care of join keys list, but how can I add the conditon as well? (note: I used identical dataframes here for simplicity)

```
 %scala
  val emp = Seq((1,"Smith",-1,"2018","10","M",3000),
    (2,"Rose",1,"2010","20","M",4000),
  )
  val empColumns = Seq("emp_id","name","superior_emp_id","year_joined","dept_id","gender","salary")
  import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
  val empDF = emp.toDF(empColumns:_*) 
  val empDF2 = emp.toDF(empColumns:_*) 


val join_keys = Seq("emp_id","name") // this will be a parameter
val joinExprs = join_keys.map{case (c1) => empDF(c1) === empDF2(c1)}.reduce(_ && _) 

// How do I add to joinExprs, another joinExpr like "empDF2(dept_id) == 10" here?

empDF.join(empDF2,joinExprs,"inner").show(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append to `joinExprs` with `&&`:

```
empDF.join(empDF2,joinExprs && empDF2("dept_id") === 10,"inner").show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael. Will try that. What if I want to send the joinExprs && "empDF2("dept_id") === 10" as a parameter, what type would that be.

Comment: it should be of type `Column`

Comment: so will it be like `val joinExprCol = empDF2("dept_id") === 10`
looks a little strange