# Spark Join: analysis exception reference is ambiguous

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, dataframe

Hi I'm trying to join two dataframes in spark, and I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'Adapazari' is ambiguous, 
could be: Adapazari#100064, Adapazari#100065.;
```

According to several sources, this can occur when you try to join two different dataframes together that both have a column with the same name ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778664/spark-dataframe-distinguish-columns-with-duplicated-name), [2](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/876/is-there-a-better-method-to-join-two-dataframes-an.html), [3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11231)). However, in my case, that is not the source of the error. I can tell because (1) my columns all have different names, and (2) the `reference` indicated in the error is a value contained within the join column.

My code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder().master("local")
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("master", "spark://myhost:7077")
  .getOrCreate()

val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

import sqlContext.implicits._

val people = spark.read.json("/path/to/people.jsonl")
  .select($"city", $"gender")
  .groupBy($"city")
  .pivot("gender")
  .agg(count("*").alias("total"))
  .drop("0")
  .withColumnRenamed("1", "female")
  .withColumnRenamed("2", "male")
  .na.fill(0)

val cities = spark.read.json("/path/to/cities.jsonl")
  .select($"name", $"longitude", $"latitude")

cities.join(people, $"name" === $"city", "inner")
  .count()
```

Everything works great until I hit the join line, and then I get the aforementioned error.

The relevant lines in `build.sbt` are:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.1.0"
)
```

Comment: fyi, everything is working fine up to the join because spark is lazy, and when you are calling "count()", you are executing the dataframe. It would probably help to see an example of the json for both cities and people.

Comment: @Derek_M Your question led me to do a deeper analysis of the data. It turns out that some of the JSONL was malformed. If you like, you can answer the question with "your JSON is likely bad" and I'll give you the answer points.

Comment: Ha, no worries. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @Logister please add your comment as an answer, it is helpful to know it might be a data issue

Comment: In my case the error was caused because the key was named the same in both dataframes. So thanks. Any insight about why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this error was due to malformed JSONL. Fixing the JSONL formatting solved the problem.