# Spark Join of 2 dataframes which have 2 different column names in list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

Is there a way to `join` two `Spark Dataframes` with different column names via 2 lists?

I know that if they had the same names in a list I could do the following:

```
val joindf = df1.join(df2, Seq("col_a", "col_b"), "left")
```

or if I knew the different column names I could do this:

```
df1.join(
df2, 
df1("col_a") <=> df2("col_x")
    && df1("col_b") <=> df2("col_y"),
"left"
)
```

Since my method is expecting inputs of 2 lists which specify which columns are to be used for the `join` for each DF, I was wondering if Scala Spark had a way of doing this?

P.S
I'm looking for something like a python `pandas merge`:

```
joindf = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = list1, right_on = list2, how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect two lists of strings:

```
val leftOn = Seq("col_a", "col_b")
val rightOn = Seq("col_x", "coly")
```

Just zip and reduce:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val on = leftOn.zip(rightOn)
  .map { case (x, y) => df1(x) <=> df2(y) }
  .reduce(_ and _)

df1.join(df2, on, "left")
```

Comment: Ambiguity when both sequences have value(s) -- one or more -- that are the same.

Comment: In that case you can reference tables directly.

Comment: Still having certain issues with duplicate columns being generated after joining 'left'. Any idea how I should deal with that?

Comment: That's normal. If columns from the other table are obsolete, you can drop these later.

Comment: In order to drop, I would need to know the column names, but if both are the same, then I would have to rename each of the duplicate ones to something unique and then drop. Is there a better way of doing this? Eg. adding a "suffix" to the columns that are duplicated while joining?

Comment: It is Python but available methods are the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33778664/9613318

Answer (score 3):

You can easely define such a method yourself:

```
 def merge(left: DataFrame, right: DataFrame, left_on: Seq[String], right_on: Seq[String], how: String) = {
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
      val joinExpr = left_on.zip(right_on).foldLeft(lit(true)) { case (acc, (lkey, rkey)) => acc and (left(lkey) === right(rkey)) }
      left.join(right, joinExpr, how)
    }


val df1 = Seq((1, "a")).toDF("id1", "n1")
val df2 = Seq((1, "a")).toDF("id2", "n2")

val joindf = merge(df1, df2, left_on = Seq("id1", "n1"), right_on = Seq("id2", "n2"), how = "left")
```