# PySpark dataframe: working with duplicated column names after self join

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778664/spark-dataframe-distinguish-columns-with-duplicated-name) question with slightly different setup):

```python
df3 = hive_context.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=107831, f=3),
    Row(a=107531, f=2),
    Row(a=125231, f=2)
])
```

Based on this, i create two new objects. Each is a subset of the original dataframe:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df1 = (df3
  .filter(((col('a') == 107831) & (col('f') == 3))|
          ((col('a') == 125231) & (col('f') == 2))))

df2 = (df3
  .filter(((col('a') == 107831) & (col('f') == 3))|
          ((col('a') == 107531) & (col('f') == 2))))
```

Then, I would like to join those two datasets and obtain the `f` columns from each of them as in:

```python
a = (df1
  .join(df2, (df1['a'] == df2['a']), how = 'full')
  .select(df1['f'], df2['f']).collect())
```

However, I get `[Row(f=None, f=None), Row(f=2, f=2), Row(f=3, f=3)]`

Instead of the desired `[Row(f=3, f=4), Row(f=None, f=2), Row(f=2, f=None)]` or expressed as a table:

```python
+------+----+------+----+
|     a|   f|     a|   f|
+------+----+------+----+
|107831|   3|107831|   4|
|  null|null|107531|   2|
|125231|   2|  null|null|
+------+----+------+----+
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Do i have to store df1 and df2 somewhere?

When I run the scenario as in the above linked question, i get the expected results:

```python
df1 = hive_context.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=107831, f=3),
    Row(a=125231, f=2),
])

df2 = hive_context.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=107831, f=4),
    Row(a=107531, f=2),
])

a = df1.join(df2, (df1['a'] == df2['a']), how = 'full').select(df1['f'], df2['f']).collect()
a
```

I run it on `python 3.6` and `spark 2.3`

Comment: the join conditions are different

Comment: @AnkitKumarNamdeo That was a typo, thank you for catching it. However, it has no impact on the described behavior. PySpark still always calls the column from dataframe on left side of the join

Comment: they both should produce the same output can you please run them again, i think the joining condition was the only problem

Comment: It is not. I tried it on actual dataset, i tried it on sample dataset. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases where there are duplicated column names, use aliases on your DataFrames to avoid the ambiguity:

```python
a = df1.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), on='a', how = 'full').select('l.f', 'r.f').collect()
print(a)
#[Row(f=3, f=3), Row(f=None, f=2), Row(f=2, f=None)]
```

Comment: I was using another approach: `df1.join(df2, (df1['a'] == df2['a']), how = 'full').toDF('a_1', 'f_1', 'a_2', 'f_2').select('f_1', 'f_2').collect()` However, i like yours better. Thank you!