# Join several dataframes and handling ambiguous columns with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe and after adding a rank column i can split it to several dataframes based on th number of ranks :

rankedDF :

| job_id | task_id | rating | proba | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 1 | 0.7 | 1 |
| 1 | 111 | 2 | 0.3 | 1 |
| 1 | 122 | 4 | 0.9 | 2 |
| 1 | 122 | 7 | 0.1 | 2 |
| 1 | 133 | 3 | 0.6 | 3 |
| 1 | 133 | 1 | 0.4 | 3 |

To create multiple dataframes :

```
val numberRanks = rankedDF.select("rank").distinct().count().toInt

// create multiple dataframe
val rankDFs = for (i <- 1 to numberRanks) yield {
rankedDF.filter(col("rank") === i)
}
```

Then I join between the dataframes and create arrays to combine rating between them, task_id between them and multiply proba between thems :

```
// join dataframes between them 
val joinedDFs = rankDFs.reduce((df1, df2) => 
df1.join(df2, Seq("job_id"))
.withColumn("combination_ratings", array(col("rating"), col("rating"))
.withColumn("combination_task", array(col("task_id"), col("task_id"))
.withColumn("final_proba", col("proba") * col("proba"))
).select("job_id", "combination_task", "combination_ratings", "final_proba")
```

The intermediate result just after the join and before creation of the combination arrays is :

| job_id | task_id | rating | proba | task_id | rating | proba | task_id | rating | proba |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 1 | 0.1 | 122 | 3 | 0.7 | 133 | 3 | 0.6 |
| 1 | 111 | 2 | 0.3 | 122 | 4 | 0.4 | 133 | 1 | 0.2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

After combination the result should be somthing like this :

| job_id | combination_task | combination_ratings | final_proba |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [111, 122, 133] | [1, 4, 3] | 0.378 |
| 1 | [111, 122, 133] | [2, 7, 1] | 0.012 |

But I get error :

`reference 'rating' is ambiguous, could be: rating, rating`

Ps : I also tried to aliasing dataframes in the join expression but the error was same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spark join causing column id ambiguity error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511560/spark-join-causing-column-id-ambiguity-error)

Comment: Ps : I also tried to aliasing dataframes in the join expression but the error was same

Comment: @GaëlJ, no this not answer my question, il also have same error : `Reference 'a.rating' is ambiguous, could be: a.rating, a.rating`

Comment: @GaëlJ, here the difference is in the number of dataframe to join, in my example is 3 dataframes, it could be 4 or more, the idea is to join dataframes 2 by 2 to get the final dataframe and the arrays

Answer (score 0):

Getting a step back and looking into the final results you need, it seems you just need to group by `job_id` and use `collect_set`/`collect_list` instead of splitting into multiple dataframes and trying to join, something like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val combinedRanksByJob = rankedDF.groupBy("job_id").agg(
    collect_set("task_id").as("combination_task"),
    collect_set("rating").as("combination_ratings"),
    aggregate("proba", lit(1.0), (acc, nxt) => acc * nxt).as("final_proba")
)

combinedRanksByJob .show(false)
```