# How to avoid duplicated columns after join operation?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Scala it's easy to avoid duplicate columns after join operation:

```
df1.join(df1, Seq("id"), "left").show()
```

However, is there a similar solution in PySpark? If I do `df1.join(df1, df1["id"] == df2["id"], "left").show()` in PySpark, I get two columns `id`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Dataframe distinguish columns with duplicated name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778664/spark-dataframe-distinguish-columns-with-duplicated-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options :

```
1. Use outer join
aDF.join(bDF, "id", "outer").show()

2. Use Aliasing: You will lose data related to B Specific Id's in this.
aDF.alias("a").join(bDF.alias("b"), aDF.id == bDF.id, "outer").drop(col("b.id")).show()

3. Use drop to drop the columns
columns_to_drop = ['ida', 'idb']
df = df.drop(*columns_to_drop)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Also I've just realized that `df1.join(df1,"id")` joins well and gives 1 `id` column.