# pyspark drop duplicate column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark 2.4.0, I have an dataframe with below columns

```
a,b,b
0,1,1.0
1,2,2.0
```

Without any join I have to keep only either one of b column and remove other b column

How can I achieve this

Comment: you have to avoid this, because a column selection by name is simply not possible when you have duplicates. If this is the result of a join, you can define prefixes or suffixes for column names. On this way you have a unique selector for 'b'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33779190/8386455

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is helpful -

```scala
 val df = Seq((0, 1, 1.0), (1, 2, 2.0)).toDF("a", "b", "b")
 df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+---+---+
      * |a  |b  |b  |
      * +---+---+---+
      * |0  |1  |1.0|
      * |1  |2  |2.0|
      * +---+---+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- b: double (nullable = false)
      */
    df.toDF("a", "b", "b2").drop("b2").show(false)
    /**
      * +---+---+
      * |a  |b  |
      * +---+---+
      * |0  |1  |
      * |1  |2  |
      * +---+---+
      */
```

Comment: I have around 200 columns with few of multiple pairs like this . Yes one option is to rename and drop . Manual effort is somewhere required. For me I have to identify and rename the list[column names] accordingly

Comment: I think its easy to do for multiple columns. Give atry

Answer (score 1):

i have been in the same situation when i made a jointure.
the good practice is to rename the columns before joining the tables:
you can refer to this link:

[Spark Dataframe distinguish columns with duplicated name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778664/spark-dataframe-distinguish-columns-with-duplicated-name)

selecting the one column from two columns of same name is confusing, so the good way to do it is to not have columns of same name in one dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
col_select = list(set(df.columns))
df_fin = df.select(col_select)
```

Comment: No still I get as ambihious

Comment: can you post these two output :
````col_list = df.columns````<post output> ````col_sel = list(set(col_list))````<post_output>

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,

Convert your DataFrame into RDD and extract the fields you want and convert back into DataFrame,

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda l: Row(a=l[0], b=l[1]))

required_df = spark.creataDataFrame(rdd)

+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  0|  1|
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

As a suppliment of Som's answer to automatically change multiple columns using cumcount:

```
ls_old = df.columns
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'ls_old':ls_old,'value':0})
pandas_df['ls_new'] = pandas_df['ls_old'] + ['' if i=='0' for i in pandas_df.groupby(['ls_old']).cumcount().astype(str)]
ls_new= list(df['ls_new'])
ls_keep = list(set(ls_new).intersection(ls_old))
df2 = df.toDF(*ls_new).select(ls_keep)
```